# Linear system in polar coordinates

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, non-linear-systems, linear-systems

Unlike the Cartesian coordinates, I find navigating through polar coordinates difficult. Is the system defined by the following Lagrangian $L$ defined in polar coordinates linear?
$$L = \frac{1}{2} m \left( \dot{r}^2 + r^2 \dot{\theta}^2 \right) - Dar^2 - \frac{K}{2} \theta ^2,$$
where $D$, $a$ and $K$ are constant positive real numbers and $r$, $\theta$ are the coordinates of the system in the polar representation. In addition $m$ is the mass of the particle.

Comment: What does it mean for a system to be linear?  Do you mean to ask whether the equations of motion are linear differential equations?

Comment: Yes. What you said imply the superposition principle to work.

Comment: That's a strange Lagrangian. What happens when $\theta$ gets to $2\pi$?

Comment: I am guessing for $\theta \ll 1$ ??

Comment: @NelsonVanegasA. is right for $\theta \ll 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with :

$$r(t)=\sqrt{x(t)^2+y(t)^2}$$

and

$$\tan(\varphi(t))=\varphi(t)=\frac{y(t)}{x(t)}$$

$$L\mapsto L(x,y,\dot{x},\dot{y})$$

$$L=1/2\,m \left( 1/4\,{\frac { \left( 2\,x{\it \dot{x}}+2\,y{\it \dot{y}} \right) ^
{2}}{{x}^{2}+{y}^{2}}}+ \left( {x}^{2}+{y}^{2} \right)  \left( {\frac
{{\it \dot{y}}}{x}}-{\frac {y{\it \dot{x}}}{{x}^{2}}} \right) ^{2} \right) -{
\it Da}\, \left( {x}^{2}+{y}^{2} \right) -1/2\,{\frac {K{y}^{2}}{{x}^{
2}}}
$$

your  Lagrangian with Cartesian coordinates is highly nonlinear, thus the equations of motion will be also nonlinear.

Comment: I follow in my work a similar approach. What I did is to Taylor expand the solution around the equilibrium $(0, 0)$ and only consider terms with power $\leq 1$ as suggested in @ModCon response. Thanks for the assistance and keep safe.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Compute $\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot \theta}\right)$ and check if any of the terms is of degree greater than one.

Comment: It makes sense. Thanks.